# Suppressing Null output with sparse data? A lot of zeros and little nonzeros

Tags: list-manipulation

I have sparse situation with a lot of zeros, related [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12093680#12093680). I want to see only the nonzero things or nonnull things.

**Example**

> **Input**
>
> ```
> hello[ii_, jj_] := If[ii == 1, Return[True], Return[False]]
> Table[If[hello[ii, jj], {ii, jj} -> 1], {ii, 1, 5}, {jj, 1, 5}]
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> {{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1, {1, 4} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 
>    1}, {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null, Null, 
>   Null}, {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null, Null, 
>   Null}}
> ```
>
> **Intended Output**
>
> ```
> {{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1, {1, 4} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1}
> ```

where the full form of the intended output could be a 5x5 matrix with 1st row with ones and otherwise zeros.

Comment: You may want to study the documentation for `SparseArray` and `ArrayRules`.

Comment: Do you realize that neither your Output nor your intended Output is a SparseArray?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're thinking of:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; hello[i, j] :> 1}, {5, 5}] // Normal

(* {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

---

Answer to edited question:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; hello[i, j] :> 1}, {5, 5}] // ArrayRules
(* {{1, 4} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {1, 1} -> 1, {_, _} -> 0} *)
```

or

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; hello[i, j] :> 1}, {5, 5}] // ArrayRules // Most // Sort
(* {{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1, {1, 4} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1} *)
```

The `Sort` is optional, depending on whether the output has to be exactly the same as the intended output.

Comment: What do `/;` and `:>` mean?

Comment: I have a far larger problem `Table[If[MiNotJ[ii, jj, mcstable[[All, kk]]] != Null, {ii, jj}], {ii, 
  1, 31}, {jj, 1, 31}, {kk, 1, 147}]` which I tried to formulate in terms of the SparseArray `SparseArray[{{ii_, jj_} /; MiNotJ[ii, jj, mcstable[[All, kk]]] -> 
   1}, {31, 31}]` but working. I need to test all combinations with 31x31 matrix.

Comment: @hhh Select them and press F1

Comment: @hhh See also the Rules and Patterns section of [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

Comment: In your `SparseArray` code `kk` is undefined and `MiNotJ` should return `True` or `False`, like `hello`.  (But comments are not for solving side-problems.  You can trying pinging me in chat if you need further help.)